# Passing multiple parameters in HTTP POST request in React JS

Tags: reactjs

This is how I request from the post request.

```js
 handleSubmit = e => {
        this.setState({ buttonload : true });
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
          if (!err) {
            fetch("api/Authentication/Login", {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
              body: JSON.stringify({
                data:{
                  CompanyCode : this.props.selectedCompany,
                  Username : values.username,
                  Password : values.password
                }
              })
             })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
              (result) => {
                console.log(result)
              },
              // Note: it's important to handle errors here
              // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
              // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
              (error) => {
                this.setState({ buttonload : false });
                console.log(error)
              })
          }
        });
      };
```

This is the post request where I want to pass the parameters

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
        public LoginModel Login(DTO_Login data)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage LoginRequest = API.PostResponse("api/Accounting/User/Login", data);
            LoginRequest.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            LoginModel Result = LoginRequest.Content.ReadAsAsync<LoginModel>().Result;
            return Result;
        }
```

This is the body parameter of the api request.

```cs
public class DTO_Login
    {
        public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

I was able to call the post request but the `data` parameter is not working as I expected after the successful execution of request the `data` parameter is null.

Comment: Can you include the code for the entire function calling the fetch? This function `API.PostResponse("api/Accounting/User/Login", data);`? Is this the one "losing" the data object?

Comment: @DrewReese starting from the `public LoginModel Login(DTO_Login data)` the `data` doesnt have values.

Comment: @DrewReese I've added the function sir.

Comment: What calls `Login` with some `data` object? Is `data` defined there? Can you share *that* code as well?

Comment: I've tried on making an `data` object from `handleSubmit ` same with the `DTO_Login` model of the post request yet the parameters are still null after reaching the post request.

Comment: just edited the question sir @DrewReese

Comment: Is your issue then in `handleSubmit`? Seems completely unrelated to the other two code snippets. Can you please provide more complete code samples, or post/host your code in an online code sandbox that reproduces your issue? It isn't clear what `data` you refer to, if it isn't defined in `Login` then it is getting passed `undefined` as a parameter, and there is no `data` variable in your submit handler.

Comment: I am able to call the api request but the parameter passed from the request is null and yes it is `handleSubmit` it seems like the issue is on how I build the parameter data of the fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please have a look I hope it's helpful to send data.
thanks

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.example.com/items",data:{ CompanyCode :this.props.selectedCompany, Username : values.username,Password : values.password})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result);
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
  }
```

Comment: Does this actually execute? Also, promise-chain catch blocks are completely OK to use.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` 

it doesnt reach the api request sir.

Comment: It's about your API result, API response should be JSON and I update code console your result and map as per your result

Comment: @SanatGupta I have a breakpoint on my API sir, it doesnt even triggered after the request of the fetch.

Comment: @Keith please do one this just print your post data on Your API section then you get your data.

Comment: sir I have tried your proposed code for the fetch and the calling doesn't even triggered. It doesn't reach the Post Request and it prompts an error within few seconds.

Comment: Please follow this URL https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/fetch-api/fetch-post.html